# Finding the topmost item in a denormalized hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with a set of tables that establishes a denormalized location structure with the following schema:

```
Location     (Name,Id)
Sublocation1 (Name,Id,LocationId)
Sublocation2 (Name,Id,Sublocation1Id)
Sublocation3 (Name,Id,Sublocation2Id)
```

And a table that tracks the association between a user and each level:

```
UserLocation (User,LocationId,Sublocation1Id,Sublocation2Id,Sublocation3Id)
```

Access to a higher level location grants access to any level under it, so the second row in the following example is superfluous, but the third row is not:

```
User  Location       Sublocation1   Sublocation2    Sublocation3
----------------------------------------------------------------
Joe   Houston Plant  West Building  NULL            NULL
Joe   Houston Plant  West Building  Third Floor     Room 42
Joe   Houston Plant  East Building  Second Floor    Room 21
```

The third row grants Joe access to *just* room 21, but not other Sublocation3s under Second Floor

---

**Question**: How can I find all the records that grant the highest level of access without granting additional permissions to Joe? My goal is to be able to trim all these extraneous entries out of my database.

I can see a number of ways to solve this, but nothing that I've been able to translate into set-based logic to make a good query.

Comment: So, the query should return just the second row, because it grants access to the room 42, to which Joe has access already due to the first row, which gives him access to all floors of `West Building` and all rooms there. Have I understood you correctly? Could you add few more rows to the sample data with explanation which of them should and shouldn't be returned by the query, please. If would help to understand the required logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE UserLocation(
    UserId int,
    LocationId int,
    Sublocation1Id int,
    Sublocation2Id int,
    Sublocation3Id int
)
```

The following query gives you the highest level accesses:

```
-- Highest level access:

SELECT * -- Level 3 grants with no higher level grants
FROM UserLocation UL
WHERE
    UL.Sublocation3Id IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * --  higher level grant
        FROM UserLocation UL1
        WHERE 
            UL1.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
            AND (UL1.Sublocation2Id IS NULL OR UL1.Sublocation2Id = UL.Sublocation2Id)
            AND (UL1.Sublocation1Id IS NULL OR UL1.Sublocation1Id = UL.Sublocation1Id)
            AND (UL1.LocationId = UL.LocationId)
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT * --  Level 2 grants with no higher level grants
FROM UserLocation UL
WHERE
    UL.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
    AND UL.Sublocation2Id IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * --  higher level grant
        FROM UserLocation UL1
        WHERE 
            UL1.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
            AND UL1.Sublocation2Id IS NULL
            AND (UL1.Sublocation1Id IS NULL OR UL1.Sublocation1Id = UL.Sublocation1Id)
            AND (UL1.LocationId = UL.LocationId)
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT * --  Level 1 grants with no higher level grants
FROM UserLocation UL
WHERE
    UL.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
    AND UL.Sublocation2Id IS NULL
    AND UL.Sublocation1Id IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * --  higher level grant
        FROM UserLocation UL1
        WHERE 
            UL1.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
            AND UL1.Sublocation2Id IS NULL
            AND UL1.Sublocation1Id IS NULL
            AND (UL1.LocationId = UL.LocationId)
    )
SELECT * --  Level 0 grants
FROM UserLocation UL
WHERE
    UL.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
    AND UL.Sublocation2Id IS NULL
    AND UL.Sublocation1Id IS NULL
```

The following query shows you the superflous grants:

```
-- Superflous grants (there is higher level grants)

SELECT * -- Level 3 grants with higher level grants
FROM UserLocation UL
WHERE
    UL.Sublocation3Id IS NOT NULL
    AND EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * --  higher level grant
        FROM UserLocation UL1
        WHERE 
            UL1.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
            AND (UL1.Sublocation2Id IS NULL OR UL1.Sublocation2Id = UL.Sublocation2Id)
            AND (UL1.Sublocation1Id IS NULL OR UL1.Sublocation1Id = UL.Sublocation1Id)
            AND (UL1.LocationId = UL.LocationId)
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT * --  Level 2 grants with higher level grants
FROM UserLocation UL
WHERE
    UL.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
    AND UL.Sublocation2Id IS NOT NULL
    AND EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * --  higher level grant
        FROM UserLocation UL1
        WHERE 
            UL1.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
            AND UL1.Sublocation2Id IS NULL
            AND (UL1.Sublocation1Id IS NULL OR UL1.Sublocation1Id = UL.Sublocation1Id)
            AND (UL1.LocationId = UL.LocationId)
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT * --  Level 1 grants with higher level grants
FROM UserLocation UL
WHERE
    UL.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
    AND UL.Sublocation2Id IS NULL
    AND UL.Sublocation1Id IS NOT NULL
    AND EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * --  higher level grant
        FROM UserLocation UL1
        WHERE 
            UL1.Sublocation3Id IS NULL
            AND UL1.Sublocation2Id IS NULL
            AND UL1.Sublocation1Id IS NULL
            AND (UL1.LocationId = UL.LocationId)
    )
```

I assume that if the id of a location level `L` is null then the id of the location level `L+1` is null.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed to get my query on track. I'm not sure that it makes a performance difference, but I reordered the logic to start from highest location level (0).

Answer (score 1):

Let's presume that `UserLocation` table has an `Id` column.
If it doesn't you can generate one using `ROW_NUMBER`.

In order to identify `strong` rules (the minimum set of existing access rules that is equivalent to all existing rules) or `weak` rules (a set of existing rules that are redundant because they are also covered by other "stronger" rules) you can join the `UserLocation` table with itself:

```
with access as (
  select * from ( values
    (1, 'Joe',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  NULL,              NULL    ),
    (2, 'Joe',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  'Third Floor',    'Room 42'),
    (3, 'Joe',   'Houston Plant',  'East Building',  'Second Floor',   'Room 21'),

    (4, 'Mark',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  NULL,             NULL    ),
    (5, 'Mark',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  'Third Floor',    'Room 42'),
    (6, 'Mark',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  'Second Floor',   'Room 21'),

    (7, 'Bob',   null,              null,             NULL,             NULL    ),
    (8, 'Bob',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  'Third Floor',    'Room 42'),
    (9, 'Bob',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  'Second Floor',   'Room 21')
   ) as v(Id, Usr, Location1, Location2, Location3, Location4)
)
select  distinct
        weak.* -- or strong.* 
from    access strong
        inner JOIN
        access weak on  weak.Usr = strong.Usr
                    and weak.Id <> strong.Id
                    and (strong.Location1 is null or weak.Location1 = strong.Location1)
                    and (strong.Location2 is null or weak.Location2 = strong.Location2)
                    and (strong.Location3 is null or weak.Location3 = strong.Location3)
                    and (strong.Location4 is null or weak.Location4 = strong.Location4)
```

**Edit:**

I figured out that there might be rules that are unique for user like:

```
(10, 'John',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  'Third  Floor',  'Room 42'),
(11, 'Ana',   'Houston Plant',  'West Building',  NULL,         NULL    )
```

Since the above query uses an `INNER JOIN` these rules are not reported in any set (`weak` or `strong`) but if you think about it you can consider that these rules are `neutral` so to speak because:

- they do not override other rules
- they are not overridden by other rules

Comment: This is really impressive for its compactness. I added a filter for the Location level 0, but otherwise, this seems exactly right for SQL. Thank you very much for responding!